# Could not load my trained file .h5 with tf.keras.models.load_model()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have trained and saved the model with `Model.save()`
it worked fine and saved the model on my device.

then I tried to load it with

```
siamese_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('siamesemodelv2.h5',custom_objects={'L1Dist':L1Dist,'BinaryCrossentropy':tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy})
```

I must pass the `L1Dist` class

this is the class

```
class L1Dist(Layer):
    
# Init method - inheritance
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
       
# similarity calculation
    def call(self, input_embedding, validation_embedding):
        return tf.math.abs(input_embedding - validation_embedding)
```

when I run the code, it shows this error

```
>  File "c:/Users/xa3/Desktop/face-recogntion.py", line 383, in <module>
    siamese_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('siamesemodelv2.h5',custom_objects={'L1Dist':L1Dist,'BinaryCrossentropy':tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy})
  File "C:\Users\xa3\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\xa3\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1392, in process_node
    inbound_node = inbound_layer._inbound_nodes[inbound_node_index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any idea? thank you so much

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you might need to import the custom layer class onto your py script

Comment: i did it 
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer, Conv2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Input, Flatten

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by downgrade Tenserflow version to 2.4.1